# Write this piece of Java in C?

Tags: java, c

I am not a C programmer. I have just started reading K&R's TCPL last week.
I have written this 42 line code in Java. I tried converting it to C, but it is giving me a segmentation fault.

Here is the Java version: http://codepaste.net/m8jz6m

My failed attempt to port it to C:

```
//Not working.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
void caesar ( const int SIDE )
{    
    int array [SIDE] [SIDE] ;

    for ( int number = 1; number <= SIDE * SIDE; ++ number )
        array [ getY ( number, SIDE ) ] [ getX ( number, SIDE ) ] = number ;

    for ( int Y = 0; Y < SIDE; ++ Y ) {
        for ( int X = 0; X < SIDE; ++ X)
            printf ( sprintf ("%%%dd" , strlen(itoa(SIDE*SIDE))), array [Y] [X] );
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
 
int getX ( const int number, const int SIDE )
{
    return SIDE == 1 ? 0 : number > 4 * SIDE - 4 ? 1 + getX ( number - 4 * SIDE + 4, SIDE - 2 ) : number >= 3 * SIDE - 2 ? 0 : number >= 2 * SIDE - 1 ? 3 * SIDE - 2 - number : number > SIDE ? SIDE - 1 : number - 1 ;
}
 
int getY ( const int number, const int SIDE )
{
    return SIDE == 1 ? 0 : number > 4 * SIDE - 4 ? 1 + getY ( number - 4 * SIDE + 4, SIDE - 2 ) : number >= 3 * SIDE - 2 ? 4 * SIDE - 3 - number : number  >= 2 * SIDE - 1 ? SIDE - 1 : number > SIDE ? number - SIDE : 0 ;
}
 
void main ( int argc, char *argv )
{
    if ( argc == 0 )
        printf ("\tUsage: java Caesar [side] | side:> Length and breadth of the square.\n");
    else
        caesar ( atoi( argv[1] ) );
}
 
 void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
     int i, sign;

     if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
         n = -n;          /* make n positive */
     i = 0;
     do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
         s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
     } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
     if (sign < 0)
         s[i++] = '-';
     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(s);
 }

  /* reverse:  reverse string s in place */
 void reverse(char s[])
 {
     int i, j;
     char c;

     for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
         c = s[i];
         s[i] = s[j];
         s[j] = c;
     }
 }
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: In which line do you get the segfault?

Comment: You should not make people follow links to be able to answer your question. Post the code in this question. If it's too big, then you should probably modify your question anyway.

Comment: And if you converted it "because C is faster than Java", you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: Damn, signature mismatch for itoa ( ). Will keep you folks updated.

Comment: @Aaron Why would that be? Almost everything runs faster in C.

Comment: What's with all the `?:` operators, try converting them if/else, this might not solve your problem but it will make it a lot clearer for somebody else trying to solve it.

Comment: @Angad: As I said: that's a myth. Just because a lot of people believe it, doesn't make it more true.

Comment: @Angad: The program's too small and carries too small of a load to make any difference between the two languages. How much faster can you expect it to be? I don't know how C compares apples to apples with Java, but even IF you manage to speed this up with C, it'd be in the 0.001 seconds range. In addition, it doesn't seem like there's much of a difference between the two, anymore.

Comment: look at the parameters required by `sprintf` and `printf` and finish K&R

Comment: Compiling this under gcc generates a rash of warnings. If you are getting these, you shouldn't ignore them.

Comment: Okay, I am incredibly embarrassed right now, and I know should be. That code is arguably the ugliest any of you C programmers have seen. No function prototypes, an argument count mismatch, and the sprintf usage. Really, really sorry.

Comment: As a general rule, if the line takes up more than 80ish characters of screen width, consider wrapping or rewriting it. That ternary operator usage is really, really bad. Don't nest them; use `if` and `else`. It doesn't affect performance and does affect readability.

Comment: @Nathon Sorry, will keep that in mind. Obviously it doesn't affect performance, for memory references made are same in any alternative and itself, but I find it easy to write such ternaries. Actually, if you knew what the program was for, you'd find it surprisingly easy to read. Try running the Java version with input as 3, 4, or 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You are calling your `itoa()` function with one argument, while the function actually expects two.
- Also, it seems that this line:

  ```
  array [ getY ( number, SIDE ) ] [ getX ( number, SIDE ) ] = number ;
  ```

  could be better expressed with something like:

  ```
  array[number / SIDE][number % SIDE] = number;
  ```

  without using those `getX` and `getY` functions (that are curiously recursive). I haven't examined those functions in detail to see what they actually do, but you may consider the above modification in any case.
- `sprintf()` is called with incorrect arguments. The first parameter should be the destination buffer. You seem to be using it as if it returned a string (it doesn't).
- Look up the function of `*` inside a printf format specifier.

Comment: What the code is supposed to do:

> java Caesar 3 
OUTPUT:
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5

(EDIT: That' wasn't worth it. Didn't know \n's get removed. There is one \n after each 3 numbers in the output.

--

An inward - spiralling array.

Answer (score 1):

Memory management is often the Achilles' Heel. Read the parts about malloc() and free(). Look for problem spots where you handle strings and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I second Greg and Yuval's answers. In particular you need to **allocate some space** before you call itoa(). Where is `itoa` storing its output? 
You are then calling `strlen` on the output of `itoa`. but `itoa` returns `void`!

```
int n,x;
...
char* outpt = (char*)malloc(30);
itoa(x, outpt);
n=strlen(outpt);
```

Also, you should really pass a third parameter to `itoa`: the buffer length.
If the method generates a very long nstring, you could be in trouble! kin `itoa` you should check after incrementing `i` each time whether it is greater than the buffer lengt

Answer (score 0):

the critical line:

```
 printf ( sprintf ("%%%dd" , strlen(itoa(SIDE*SIDE))), array [Y] [X] );
```

the sprintf's first argumet shoulb be a string.

not the problem, but:
i got very confused reading your code: in "C", uppercase names are for Constants (#defines), not for const typed variables.

itoa() is defeined with two parameters and invoked with one.

you are using much too many spaces.

it is "i++" and not "i ++" in C (not that it matters syntactically, but reading-wise).

Comment: Are there any official coding conventions for C? I always thought there weren't... Still, I also prefer using capital letters only for compile time constants...

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- You're calling your own `itoa` function with 1 argument but you've declared it to take 2 arguments
- You're taking the `strlen()` of your itoa function , but have declared it with a return type of `void`
- Your use of sprintf is wrong, sprinf needs a buffer to place the result in.

Compile your program with warnings enabled, you should get warnings about most of these.

Answer (score 0):

the `itoa` you're calling is not the `itoa` you've declared. Comment out `#include <stdlib.h>` and you should get a compile error instead of just warnings.